# MVC Controller throws null reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On My DB context class I have code like this

```
  modelBuilder.Entity("WebApplication10.Data.JobCategory", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("ID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<string>("JobCategoryName");

                b.Property<int>("JobCategoryParentID");

                b.Property<string>("jobCategoryDetails");

                b.HasKey("ID");

                b.ToTable("JobCategory");
            });
```

And on my controller

```
 private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View( _context.JobCategory.ToList());
    }
```

but on my controller class I get an error like this

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebApplication10.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you ever initializing your `_context` variable?

Comment: put a breakpoint and inspect your variables(Ex:_context) and see whether it (or a property which you are accessing) is null

Comment: suggestion: Practice placing debug point, in order to debug issues.It helps a lot and some time solution is in the error itself. .net framework is very smart, and uses meaningful names.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson nop, can you tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `_context` variable has never been initialized so how can you access its `JobCategory` property?

The runtime throwing a `NullReferenceException` **always** means the same thing: you are trying to use a reference. The reference is not initialized (or it was initialized, but is no longer initialized).

This means the reference is `null`, and you cannot access members through a `null` reference. The simplest case:

```
string foo = null;
foo.ToUpper();
```

This will throw a `NullReferenceException` at the second line, because you can't call the instance method `ToUpper()` on a `string` reference pointing to `null`.

Initial your variable like this:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Comment: Can you show me, How I could make that?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks, But I have already done this before like this
  private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
But its still not working

Comment: Have you added the initialization part: `= new ApplicationDbContext()`?